# Wix installer: create shortcut to open a folder

Tags: wix, installation, shortcut

I am new to Wix and installation issues in general, so would appreciate any help on the following.
I want to do a fairly standard application installation (TestApp.exe), but I want the install folder to have a subfolder containing a tutorial document and several sample files. I want the application subfolder in Start Programs (ProgramMenuFolder) to have 3 shortcuts: 1) to the application exe itself, 2) to a tutorial.docx file, and 3) to the subfolder containing tutorial.docx + the sample files. The idea of the last shortcut is that clicking it should open the folder in Explorer, so that the user can access the sample files to load into the application.
My problem is that I don't know how to write a shortcut to a folder. Here is my code which works OK for the general installation and first two shortcuts. It includes my pathetic attempt at the third shortcut. It compiles OK, but fails to write the shortcut to the folder
I would greatly appreciate advice on how to implement the third shortcut.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

    <Product Id="*" Name="TestApp" Language="1033" Version="2.0.0.0" Manufacturer="W J Heitler" UpgradeCode="be9cef4c-d9e8-488e-b69d-00b7d1f1250b">
        <Package Id="*" InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." /> 
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab='yes'/>

    <Feature Id='Complete' Title ='TestApp Complete' Level='1'>
      <ComponentGroupRef Id='ProductComponents' />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id='Shortcuts' />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id='TutorialStuff' />
    </Feature>

    <Icon Id="TestApp.exe" SourceFile="..\Release\TestApp.exe" />

  </Product>

<!--Directories-->
  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="TestApp" >
          <Directory Id="INSTALLDIRTUTORIAL" Name="Tutorial" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="Programs">
        <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="TestApp"/>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>  
  </Fragment>

<!--Bits to install-->
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLDIR">
      <Component Id="MainExecutable" Guid="{E758641D-5794-412B-97FD-A7879C276947}">
        <File Id="TestAppEXE" Source="$(var.TestApp.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes" >
          <Shortcut Id="TestApp" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Name="TestApp" WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' Icon="TestApp.exe" IconIndex="0" Advertise="yes" />
        </File>
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>

    <ComponentGroup Id='Shortcuts' Directory='ProgramMenuDir'>
      <Component Id="ProgramMenuShortcut"  Guid="{EBFD85FD-27B4-48CE-9AE3-E7B186A7F797}">
        <RemoveFolder Id='ProgramMenuDir' On='uninstall' />
        <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]' Type='string' Value='' KeyPath='yes' />
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>

    <ComponentGroup Id ='TutorialStuff' Directory='INSTALLDIRTUTORIAL'>
      <Component Id ='Tutorial' Guid='{02DDC1B6-DFBB-488F-BDEF-8D32D95DEBC4}' >
        <File Id='TutorialDoc' Source='samples\tutorial.docx' KeyPath='yes' >
          <Shortcut Id='TutorialSC' Directory='ProgramMenuDir' Name='Tutorial' WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIRTUTORIAL' Advertise="yes" />
        </File>
      </Component>

      <!-- THIS DOES NOT WORK-->
      <Component Id ='SampleDir' Guid='{E9EAE95A-8234-406D-950D-397956287709}' >
        <Shortcut Id='SampleDirSC' Directory='ProgramMenuDir' Name='Samples' Target ='INSTALLDIRTUTORIAL' />
        <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]' Type='string' Value='' KeyPath='yes' />
      </Component>
      <!--END OF FAILED CODE-->
  </ComponentGroup>

  </Fragment>

</Wix>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the thing you missed is to enclose the identifier of the directory in the `Target`-attribute by square brackets, so Windows Installer can resolve the directory correctly. Note also that the shortcut itself has to be non-advertised in this case. I would also include the `Directory`-attribute to the surrounding component as you did with the other components. So the following should work:

```
  <Component Id ='SampleDir' Guid='{Add_your_guid_here}' Directory='INSTALLDIRTUTORIAL' >
    <Shortcut Id='SampleDirSC' Directory='INSTALLDIRTUTORIAL' Name='Samples' Target ='[INSTALLDIRTUTORIAL]' Advertise='no' />
    <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]' Type='string' Value='' KeyPath='yes' />
  </Component>
```

See also the WiX documentation regarding the `Target`-attribute of the `Shortcut`-element:

> This attribute's value is the target for **a non-advertised shortcut**. This attribute is not valid for advertised shortcuts. If you specify this value, *its value should be a property identifier enclosed by square brackets ([ ])*, that is expanded into the file or a folder pointed to by the shortcut.

Comment: @Paddy: I don't know how to comment on edits. In this case, removing the GUID doesn't fit the solution of the concrete problem anymore. Whatever.